# Good logic of View helper for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Could someone tell what is good logic for creating custom helper for Views?

What I would like to accomplish is...

- load header
- load main navigation (static for all pages)
- load some widgets etc. (static for all pages)
- load content/main pages (dynamic)
- and in the end, load footer of course

Could someone point me to the solution?

Thanks a lot, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Template library that is more actively developed than Collin's (linked by predrag.music) try out mine:

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

His is good but this supports modules, themes, mobile version variations of themes and plenty more.

Comment: I think I will stick with your library ;-) I would like you to correct a mistake you made in documentation... In "Cool Shit", "Module support" links to "Mobile support" and vice versa... Thanks for your answer...

Comment: Answers should be fully self-contained... otherwise your presently dead link wouldn't be as much of an issue.

Comment: I think the code is available as a spark: http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show (where the same broken link is provided as the documentation page)

Answer (score 2):

Some people will create a master template, then pass the sub content's view name in the data object. The master template will call the header view, footer view, etc, and use the data array to dynamically display the correct sub content view.

Comment: +1. That's exactly what I do, but I break it down even a little further: I pass in the sub content view, along with another array containing initialization data. The sub view is responsible for loading any 'part' views associated with it. I like clean code :)

Answer (score 2):

This question gives some explanation to the method dqhendricks describes.  It includes code examples showing how to use `$this->load->view()` to return the view to a variable instead of outputting it to the browser, how to include sub-views, and using a specific view as your main template.  It's the best way I've found of handling view logic.     [Getting the hang of CodeIgniter - Templating / loading views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146215/getting-the-hang-of-codeigniter-templating-loading-views/4146352#4146352)

Answer (score 1):

you could use inheritance chaining (with a custom controller class or with an included extra class that extends controller that you extend from your controllers instead of the controller class) to make a common controller hub for all pages that has a method for the top stuff, and a method for the bottom stuff.

Comment: Could you point me to some community created  package for this? I dont mind to code it on my own... I just need great logic

Comment: I don't know of one, sorry. This would be a class with a few methods. Should be REALLY simply, or you are over-thinking it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something for the reference this one is good:

http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html