# how to load a header contents to be available in all the pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a controller where there are many methods, i have to load my header in all the pages. 
Currently i am using `$data["query1"] = $this->mainmenumodel->getmainmenulist();` in all the methods for loading my header data.

I have more then 30 methods in each classes, so for this it is a bit difficult to write this `$data["query1"] = $this->mainmenumodel->getmainmenulist();` in every method.

Is there anything I can do in a class so that it will be available for entire method.

controller.php

```
                       --------------------------------
                       ---------------------------------
    class mainmenusetups extends MY_Controller {
       var $data = array();
       public function __construct() { 
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
        $this->load->model('mainmenumodel'); 
        $this->load->library('pagination'); 
        parent::MY_Controller(); 

      if ((int) $mainmenu_id > 0) 
       {
        $query = $this->mainmenumodel->get($mainmenu_id); 
          $this->data->mainmenumodel->getmainmenulist();//how to specify it only once to be use for enitere  class
        $this->load->view('admin/setups/mainmenu/index', $data);
       } 

      else if (!($this->input->post('mainmenu_id'))) 

     {
        $data["query"] = $this->mainmenumodel->fetch_mainmenu_data($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
         $this->data->mainmenumodel->getmainmenulist();//how to specify it only once to be use for enitere  class
        $this->load->view('admin/setups/mainmenu/index', $data);
       }
     //--------like this ,i have many  methods and condition in every page-----------       }
```

Comment: I'm rather confused... but `$this->data->mainmenumodel->getmainmenulist();` obviously won't work, $data is an array.  Do you maybe want to pass $data to that method?  `$this->getmainmenulist($data);`?

Comment: @ficuscr  I updated my question.  I would like to pass  `$this->data->mainmenumodel->getmainmenulist();` in the entire methods of this class by specifying it only once. Currently i am specifying it in the every page.   Please help...

Comment: Most MVC frameworks have a concept of 'view helpers' to facilitate this.  I'll defer to someone familiar with codeignitor.  Seeing some other good related questions too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650957/good-logic-of-view-helper-for-codeigniter

Comment: You want a [Decorator Pattern](http://symfony.com/doc/master/quick_tour/the_view.html) that builds your view abstractly in a step-wise or managed process after a request has been processed. If you have *many methods and conditions on many pages*, I'm thinking your code base and routing methodology is way too underdeveloped for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I am using codeigniter not symphony.  I am unable to understand your comment. Can you post it as a answer by explaining with few example code?

Comment: Take a look at [this diagram of the Zend Dispatcher](http://nethands.de/download/zenddispatch_en.pdf), which is complicated, but follow it around a few times. The idea is that your view is separated in the process from the request routing and processing, until the request is ready to be mapped to a format and decorated (e.g., could be XML, REST, HTML, JSON) before sending. Think of it this way: You don't start building the output until you've passed the routing stage and (hopefully) consumed and are ready to *decorate* the response. At the end. Not as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a little muddled, I think.

Inherit all your controllers from MY_Controller. On MY_Controller, set your header to a "global" variables like:

```
$this->data['header'] = $this->set_header();

function set_header()
{
    //all my good logic, including:
    return $this->load->view('my_header', '', true);  // true will pass to a variable
}
```

Now, on all your inherited controllers, whenever you load up a view always use $this->data for your data; $this->data['header'] will be included & you can print it out at the top of your template/page