# Codeigniter default layout like in Twig

Tags: codeigniter, templates, view

I'd like to know how to implement this in codeigniter cause it's kind of a hassle to always have this code in the controller.

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('content_view',$data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

In twig, you can define a default template, base.html.twig like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and then in your content_view, you can extend that default template and add the content sent by the current controller:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %} 
... your data here ...
{% endblock %}
```

so that i only have to call this in my controller

```
$this->load->view('content_view',$data);
```

and voila, the system loads my default template along with my content_view data

i do not want to use libraries or anything like that. i want to implement this without using third party software.

edit:

I've seen one good idea here, first answer, [Getting the hang of CodeIgniter - Templating / loading views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146215/getting-the-hang-of-codeigniter-templating-loading-views?rq=1)

but it's only close to what I wanted to implement which is more like the twig template engine

Let's say I wanted to add another block to my default template, the navigation, as well as the website name and page title:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ app_name }} :: {{ page_title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navi">
    {% block navi %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

navigation.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

(% if active ? 'class="active" : '' %}

<ul>
    <li {{ active }}>Home</li>
    <li {{ active }}>About</li>
    <li {{ active }}>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

then in my controller, i have the following data i want to pass on content_view:

```
$content = array(
    'page_title' => 'About this Site', 
    'content_body' => 'blah blah, blah'
);

$data = array(
    'app_name' => 'Example',
    'page_title' => 'About',
    'active' => 'about',    // the active page to highlight in navigation
    'contents' => $content
)

$this->load->view('content_view',$data);
```

now even though the variables are in different locations, since they are all linked from one default page, the values will be printed all together.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example :: About</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navi">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li class="active">About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <h3>About this Site</h3>

    blah, blah blah
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this approach:

```
<?php
    #controller
    $data           = array();
    $data['title']  = 'Home Page';
    $data['main']   = 'index';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);   
?>
```

This is the template.php file

```
<!-- save as template.php -->
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=$title?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navi">
    <?php $this->load->view('header') ?>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <?php $this->load->view($main) ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now do all the navigation related code in the header.php file.

Comment: what if i want to pass data on the 'main' page?

Comment: `<?=` should be just `<?php` or `<?` for the lines where you load the views. `$this->load->view(view_name);` will already output the data using echo so no need to echo what is already being echoed. You would use your current method ONLY if you set the 3rd parameter to true such as `$this->load->view(view_name, '', TRUE);` which will not echo, but return the view as a string to then be echoed. See the bottom of the [view docs page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html).

Comment: this line `$this->load->view('template', $data); ` is posting the `$data` to the main page. There on the `index.php` page you will get the variables as `$title`.@user949000.

Yes, you are right ! @crypticツ.